# Nodejs backslashes in string not showing even with extra backslashes

Tags: javascript, node.js

The string in the below code:

```
spawn('geth', ['attach', "ipc:\\.\pipe\geth"+"1"+".ipc"],...
```

Shows as:

```
'ipc:\\.pipegeth1.ipc' in cmd output
```

When I use double backslashes to escape them:

```
spawn('geth', ['attach', "ipc:\\\\.\\pipe\\geth"+"1"+".ipc"],...
```

It shows as:

```
'ipc:\\\\.\\pipe\\geth1.ipc'
```

How can I get the expected output (ipc:\.\pipe\geth1.ipc")?

Comment: Seems like you should already know the answer: `"ipc:\\.\\pipe\\get"`

Comment: That is what I though as well, but it is not working. I updated my question as the format of the 'question box' was already escaping backslashes in my question. Please see above the updated results, both are not giving the required result

Answer (score 0):

You want to escape this: `ipc:\.\pipe\geth1.ipc`

For each backslash, add another backslash

`ipc:\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc`